# Git not showing changes in specific file

Tags: git, markdown

Whenever I modify a file (a `README.md` file), add it. commit and then push it to the remote repo, it updates accordingly. There's no problem with that. However, I can't see differences between commits, even when there are clearly new lines and stuff.

The `git commit` shows the following:

```
$ git commit -m "why god"
[master 4dcb4c2] why god
1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
```

I'm using git for Windows and using git bash console. `core.autocrlf` is set to `true`.

```
$ git config --global core.autocrlf
true
```

`README.md` seems the only file affected, I have a bunch of other `.tex` files and changes are shown normally.

It's not a desperate problem, but I'd like to know why this happens. Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try in bash with 'git diff <COMMIT_SHA>^ <COMMIT_SHA>' ?

Comment: @ItayB Yes, and it showed no difference at all. Strangely enough, it is now solved after rewriting the first line.I'm answering the question below. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, it is now fixed. What I did was just change the first line of my file:

```
- How are we doing?
- ===========
+ # How are we doing
```

Instead of using the alternative heading 1, used the # symbol and it's now fixed. Still no idea why this happens, though.